# How to parse the page name from a URL?

Tags: parsing, url, coldfusion

I have a URL, and I want to get the final page name out of it. For example, if my url is `http://www.mysite.com/mypage.cfm`, then I want to get the value `mypage.cfm`. I tried googling to find if there are any built-in coldfusion functions that can help me accomplish this, but I haven't been able to find any. So, what I did at first was implement a sort of "endsWith" function (which doesn't seem to be available in coldfusion either) - something like this:

```
<cfif right(cgi.http_referer, len("mypage.cfm")) EQ "mypage.cfm">
... do whatever I want to do if the page is "mypage.cfm" ...
```

This was working well... The problem is if there's a query string appended to the url this won't work. For example, if the url is `http://www.mysite.com/mypage.cfm?param=whatever`, the if statement will evaluate to false.

I can probably safely accomplish what I'm trying to do by checking if the url contains the page name using `FindNoCase`... however, this doesn't seem so intuitive or correct. What is the best way to strip out the page name from a url in coldfusion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No built in functions per se, but list functions should do:

```
<cfset pageName = listFirst(listLast(CGI.HTTP_Referer, '/'), '?')>
```

Comment: Nice one, also you can use `GetFileFromPath` for the internal step, it handles the URLs too.

Comment: @Sergii: interesting never used `GetFileFromPath()` for that purpose. I'm assuming it will strip the query string?

Comment: It would be cool, but it wont. That's why I have mentioned internal step meaning `ListLast` with slash.

Comment: @Sergii: OK, now I understand. Coulda tested it out myself, but being lazy today.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the current page name from the URL, try this:

```
 ListLast(CGI.SCRIPT_NAME, "/")
```

That will get the full path after the domain name (including the leading slash) and then return the last item from the list using the / as the separator.

Answer (score 1):

There's a UDF on CFlib that does this:
http://cflib.org/udf/GetFileFromURL